# Python Pytesseract - unable to read the image

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am new to pyteseract OCR. I was able to read simple pic and get the test message. I am unable to read test from attached png file. From the attached image, i am trying to extract ishSilver and (SLV) in text.
I would appreciate it if you could help on this. Thank you in advance.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' # actual path to tesseract
im = Image.open('Images/' + '1680.png')
            # Size of the image in pixels (size of orginal image)
            # (This is not mandatory)
width, height = im.size

# Setting the points for cropped image
left = width*.88
top = 0
right = width
bottom = height 

# Cropped image of above dimension
# (It will not change orginal image)
im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

# Capturing the image in image viewer and converting to text
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im1, lang="eng")
print(text)
print("/n")
# Finding the "(" and ")" to the actual stock ticker and save the text in symbol for placeorder to access the file
ticker = text[text.find("(")+1:text.find(")")]
print(ticker)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIV84.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvRIY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaFza.png)

Comment: You need some pre-processing of the image, e.g. rotating by 90° counter-clockwise, crop to the purple part, grayscale the image. Do all your images look like this? If not, provide more input examples to get ideas for some more general solution. If that's your only image, crop using hardcoded values.

Comment: Thank you, HansHirse... i was able to get OCR read the character to some extend but still some it read incorrectly. I have updated my code.

Comment: also, i have added few more pics

Comment: I was able to capture the text using below code.